# Optimizing Python code for efficiency

Tags: python, python-3.x

Profiling this code shows the bulk of the time is spent on the log operation. 
Is there another way to write this in Python 3 for more efficiency? Replacing the loop with a list comprehension was actually less efficient and so was map because of lambdas.

```
def log_total(data): 
    total = 0.0   
    log = log(data) 
    for i in range(10000): 
        total += log/(i+1)  
    return total
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you _really_ have to choose the same variable name as the `log` function?

Comment: You could save an addition:  `for i in range(1,10001): total += log/i`

Comment: @mgilson: Huh, that speeds it up from `1.42 msec` per loop to `1.09 msec` per loop. That's a pretty big improvement.

Comment: @mgilson, that is indeed faster!

Comment: Is your `log` function the one from the `math` module? If so, I doubt you'll be able to improve on its performance directly (since it's a built-in function implemented in C). If `log` is something you've coded for yourself, then there's might be room for improvement, but you'll have to show its code before we can suggest anything!

Comment: @Blckknght, I am indeed using the built-in log function but I was thinking using another possible library might speed things up. However, mglison's trick got me a big speed boost.

Comment: @user_noname_00 -- You can also get another (very minor) speed boost by setting a default argument:  `def log_total(data,log=log):` as this allows the lookup of the `log` function to be local to your function instead of in the global namespace.  But again, that's a pretty minor speedup and should only be used if you can demonstrate that it really makes a difference (and then with loads of documentation saying what is going on).

Answer (score 9):

I'd factor the `log` out of your summation and cache your sum:

```
harmonic_series = sum(1. / i for i in range(1, 10001))  # Thanks, @mgilson

def log_total(data): 
    return log(data) * harmonic_series
```

You could also use [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) to speed it up even more.

Comment: @user_noname_00: See my edit. There's really no way it could be slower.

Comment: Caching like this IS super fast but is like cheating :) There must be a way to optimize the function internally. When I said it was slower the sum was computed inside the function.

Comment: But, the solutions are equivalent. Even if you optimized the `log` it would still be called 10,000 times thus incurring a huge cost each time, especially when you are essentially using a static variable, but computing it each call to the method. The next step would be to use `memmoization` as stated in the other question to get an even more speed from the function.

Comment: @user_noname_00: So you want to optimize it, but it needs to stay slow?

Comment: You can do better with numpy as well:  `'(1./np.arange(1,10001)).sum()'` cuts it down by a factor of ~6 for me, (but isn't as lazy)

Comment: If you are on Python 2.x, and you insist on computing the sum within log_total, change range to xrange to avoid creating the 10,000-element list every time. (But really, this sum of `1+1/2+1/3+...+1/10000` is an invariant and should be lifted out of your looping function. Perhaps a compromise would be to include it as a default arg in log_total, so that it is computed just once at compile time instead of in every call to log_total.)

Answer (score 0):

Can write with `lambda` in on line, like this:

```
total = lambda data: log(data) * sum(1.0 / i for i in xrange(1, 10001))
```

I used `Python 2.7.3`.

Comment: I changed it . I forgot that a * b1 + a * b2 + a * bn = a * (b1 + b2 + bn).

Comment: Haha , i'm forgot write that.

Comment: Change your list comprehension to a generator. By adding the brackets, an actual list with `10000` elements is created (try changing `10001` to `1000000001` and see what happens), which takes up a ton of RAM.

Comment: Your snippet is doing integer division. Change to `1.0/i` or use `from __future__ import division`, else your sum will equate to `1+0+0+0+...`.

Comment: @Paul McGuire  `Thanks!` I learn `from__future__ import division`.